# AppMsg - Crouton library - Support for Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, crouton

I have been using AppMsg, which is a third party library for displaying alerts in a non intrusive way (originally conceived by Cyril Motier). The library is working out fine for regular activities, but does anyone know how to use the library for `Fragments`?

https://github.com/johnkil/Android-AppMsg

As can be see, the main function `makeText` needs an activity `context`. How do I pass `Fragment` to this method?

```
public static AppMsg makeText(Activity context, int resId, Style style)
{
    return makeText(context, context.getResources().getText(resId), style);
}
```

Thanks,
Torri.

Comment: got any solution for this??

Answer (score 9):

You can use my [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) library for this.

In order to display a Crouton within a Fragment simply call

```
Crouton.makeText(Activity, String, Style, (ViewGroup) getView()).show();
```

or

```
Crouton.showText(Activity, String, Style, (ViewGroup) getView());
```

Comment: it will work in child fragment ? it's not displaying anything Crouton.makeText(getActivity(), "err", Style.INFO,(ViewGroup) getView()).show();  //activity-->viewpager fragment--->childfragment

Answer (score 2):

> How do I pass Fragment to this method ?

By downloading its source code and modifying it as you see fit. At the present time, AppMsg only supports displaying a crouton at the activity level.

You can set up a crouton via AppMsg from a fragment by passing in the fragment's activity (obtained via `getActivity()`) to the `makeText()` method. However, this will still display the crouton for the activity, not for an individual fragment.

Comment: any solutions to make it available for fragment or child(nested) fragment ? (still display the crouton for the activity, not for an individual fragment) !!

Answer (score 0):

The AppMsg library has since been updated with the ability to have the crouton attached to any custom view you provide. Look for the `setParent` method.

Within a fragment, as long as you have a reference to the container view, it should be straight forward.